# Having multiple fonts in Unix text files

Tags: c++, unix, fonts

Is it possible?

Basically, we have this feature called view TTY(Teletype), and it brings up a text file which was also generated programatically in C++ using standard string manipulation functions

My question is, is there a way to have a text file on Unix with texts of different font sizes?

And if so, can the font sizes of the text in C++ before writing it to a text file? Or, does it have to be written to another format like pdf?

Please suggest whatever libraries/format you know.

Comment: text files do not have "formatting" like fonts. They're just text. If you want formatting, then use markup, like html or LaTeX

Comment: That should probably be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text files only contain text; they do not (nominally) contain
any information concerning how the text is displayed.  I say
nominally, however, because it's quite possible for another
program to interpret some of the text as markup—I've
already output LaTeX source as text, and that definitely allows
any number of fonts.

If the file is only going to be viewed by this viewer, then you
need to find out what *it* supports in the form of markup, and
insert that in the text file.  If you have several different
viewers with different conventions, you'll have to define
a neutral convention (or use an existing one, but most existing
ones are very complex), and then write filters for each of the
targeted viewers, which converts your markup to what the viewer
expects.